# setLayoutParams called from button OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to resize ImageView on button click. I don't know why but setLayoutParams works when I call it in onCreate method, but not working when use it inside button's OnClickListener. Did I miss something?

```java
ImageView myImageView;
Button myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    myImageView = findViewById(R.id.viewtest);
    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontest);

    resizeImageView(); // resize when called here

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            resizeImageView(); // NOT resize when called here

        }
    });
}

private void resizeImageView() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Resize", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)myImageView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 300;
    params.width = 300;
    myImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

XML layout. I'm using LinearLayout inside of RelativeLayout.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ResultActivity">

<android.widget.LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineartest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/viewtest"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:background="#444"
        />

</android.widget.LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/buttontest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="test"/>

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your .xml file also.

Comment: From next time, Try to add all relevant code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I've found solution. I use some async task that affects ImageView (loading image). When I disabled it resize button started to work as excepted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked. This works fine in case of ImageView.

Maybe you are resizing it multiple times. Means If you have already called `resresizeImageView()` in `onCreate` method and you call it again in OnClick method , the resizing won't be visible because it already has the size you are resizing to.

In xml, you have `AppCompatButton` but in java you have defined as `Button`. Change `AppCompatButton` to `Button` in xml Or in java, `Button` to `AppCompatButton`.

Comment: No I'm not using resizeImageView() in onCreate. Just put it in code as example. It's wired. I tried it hundred times and can't get it work in onClick.

Comment: It is the same code. I just have my own views in layout.

Comment: I posted layout xml also. Maybe I have a mistake there.

Comment: Try changing AppCompatButton to Button in xml Or in java, Button  to AppCompatButton . Everything is working here. I used your Activity and xml too.

Comment: @4timepi accept the answer if it helped and worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code, to create a new project, and just commented out the first call to `resizeImageView()` and it works fine when `resizeImageView()` is called in `onClick()`

As Derek answered, maybe you're already setting the same bounds to the ImageView during `onCreate()` which you wish to update in button click.

Also, just a suggestion:

1. Try adding the property `android:layout_below="@id/lineartest"` to your AppCompatButton.
2. Change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, so you can view the changes happening to the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    public static final float screenWidth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.the_company);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    }
}
```

And after declare this implementation:

```
 Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            float scale =  SomeActivity.screenWidth / view.getWidth();
            if(view.getScaleX() == 1) {
                view.setScaleY(scale);
                view.setScaleX(scale);
            } else{
                view.setScaleY(1);
                view.setScaleX(1);
            }
        }
    });
```